# How to match text with jquery or partial matching

Tags: jquery

I have this hyperlink in anchor tag

```
<a href="/index.php?var1=rule-power" > Text </a>
```

Now i want that when that page is clicked i have the page with hyperlinks like

```
<a href="" >rule-power </a>
```

Is it possible that i can grab the var1 using jquery . even if its partial match it willl be good and then remove that  tag

something like

```
NewVar =getParameter(var1);
$.find(a).withtext(NewVar).hide()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Artem Barger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104014/artem-barger)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery/901144#901144) to get the querystring variable, then you can use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to do a partial match, like this:

```
var var1 = getParameterByName('var1'); //from linked answer
$('a:contains("' + var1 + '")').hide();
```

Or, if you wanted an *exact* match, use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), like this:

```
var var1 = getParameterByName('var1');
$('a').filter(function() { 
  return $(this).text() == var1;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Much better (retracting answer) nice job.

Comment: +1 - Although I can't tell if OP wants to `.hide()` the tag (seems apparent from the code example) or "hide" the path in the `href` (seems apparent from the HTML). I have a feeling it is the latter if these are nav links.

Comment: @patrick - I *think* he wants to hide the tag, e.g. wants to hide the link that goes to the current page in the menu...I would disable it, turn it black, etc, but whatever the OP is after works.

Comment: thanks for that , actually i wanted to something else but that would take tto much time to write so i just use hide. The basic thing was it just wanted the element . thanks guys